# Как создавать ссылки на каталоги с помощью команды ln?

Tags: linux

Возможно ли создавать жесткие\символические ссылки на каталоги? В задании указано создать жесткую ссылку с каталога на файл, с каталога на каталог. Нигде не нашел, как именно это делается. Ссылки между файлами создаются командой `ln` без проблем.

```
ln ~/kat1/kat2 ~/kat3 

ln: /kat1/kat2: Не допускается создавать жесткие ссылки на каталоги
```

Также с файла на каталог не получается:

```
ln file1 ~/kat1/kat2
ln: Не удалось создать жесткую ссылку '~/kat1/kat2/file1': Файл существует
```

В ошибке приводится файловый путь, но в моей системе он не существует, т.к. file1 находится в каталоге kat3.

Comment: `ln -sfn /path1 /path2`, разве не так?

Comment: @Senior Pomidor, действительно так, спасибо!

Comment: @SeniorPomidor у него что-то про жёсткие ссылки, а у вас "-s"

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev точно. спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```
ln -sfn /path1 /path2
```

- `-s` - создает мягкую ссылку
- `-P` - создать жесткую ссылку.
- `-f` - если таргет файл уже существует и является каталогом, тогда удаляет его, чтобы создать ссылку. Используется в пару с `-s`, лучше не использовать этот флаг
- `-n` - если в пути есть уже мягкие ссылки, то не следовать им. Это наиболее полезно с опцией `-f`, чтобы заменить символическую ссылку, которая может указывать на каталог

достаточно использовать утилиту без параметров и будет создана жесткая ссылка. `ln source hardlink`